# AngularJS ngOptions filter array by boolean field

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ng-options

I have this array:

```
    this.chapters = {
         1: { name: 'Chapter 1', show: false },
         2: { name: 'Chapter 2', show: true },
         3: { name: 'Chapter 3', show: true }
    };
```

And I want to show only chapters whose show value is true in this select

```
<select ng-model="cart.newchapter" 
        ng-options="v.name for (k, v) in cart.chapters"></select>
```

Now it's showing all chapters, but I need to filter them. I've been trying to apply filter but It didn't work. Can you help me? Oh! I can't change boolean type of.

Comment: Put up a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @PatrickReck You can now put live html/js/css examples in-line in StackOverflow itself - See [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: I think, you cannot really apply filter on object, you would need to convert it to an array

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply filters to Objects, only to Arrays. So, you have 2 options here, change `chapters` to an Array or *pre-filter* the `chapters` Object using a function like this:

```
$scope.filter = function(chapters) {
  var result = {};
  angular.forEach(chapters, function(chapter, key) {
    if (!chapter.show) {
      return;
    }
    result[key] = chapter;
  });
  return result;
};
```

And on the HTML:

```
<select ng-model="newchapter" ng-options="v.name for (k, v) in filter(chapters)"></select>
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.chapters = {
      1: {
        name: 'Chapter 1',
        show: false
      },
      2: {
        name: 'Chapter 2',
        show: true
      },
      3: {
        name: 'Chapter 3',
        show: true
      }
    };

    $scope.filter = function(chapters) {
      var result = {};
      angular.forEach(chapters, function(chapter, key) {
        if (!chapter.show) {
          return;
        }
        result[key] = chapter;
      });
      return result;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <select ng-model="newchapter" ng-options="v.name for (k, v) in filter(chapters)"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom filter as built-in filter would not work with object (your `chapters` is object), here is a custom filer you could use

```
app.filter('objFilter',function($filter){
  return function(items,toFilter){
       var values=[];
       Object.keys(items).forEach(function(v){
         values.push(items[v]);
        });
        return $filter('filter')(values,toFilter);
  };
});


     <select ng-model="cart.newchapter" 
        ng-options="v.name for (k, v) in chapters | objFilter:{show:true} "></select>
```